# create PHP function for PDO insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have tried to create a function for an SQL/PDO Insert query:

```
function InsertQuery ($table,$cols,$values) {
    global $pdo_conn;

    foreach($values as $values2) {
        $values2 = $values2;
    }
    $stmt='INSERT into $table (';
    foreach($cols as $cols2) {
        $stmt.=" ".$cols2.", ";
    }
    $stmt.=" ) VALUES ( ";
    foreach($cols as $cols2) {
        $stmt.=" :".$cols2." ";
    }
    $stmt.=" ) ";

    $stmt2 = $pdo_conn->prepare($stmt);
    foreach($cols as $cols2) {
    $stmt2->bindParam(':$cols2', $cols2);
    }
}
```

but i am getting the error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /home/integra/public_html/admin/includes/functions.php on line 30

please be patient with me as i am new to PDO and just used to using MySQL

have i put the prepared statement wrong or my foreach loops?

I believe the statement should look like:

```
$stmt2 = $pdo_conn->prepare('INSERT into $table (col1) values (:val1)');
$stmt2->bindParam(':$val1', $val);
```

here is how i called my function:

```
$col=array('col1');
$val=array('val1');
InsertQuery ("table1",$col,$val);
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok here is my new code:

```
global $pdo_conn;
foreach($values as $values2) {
    $values2 = $values2;
}
$stmt='INSERT into '.$table.' (';
foreach($cols as $cols2) {
    $stmt.=" ".implode(",", $cols2)." ";
}
$stmt.=" ) VALUES ( ";
foreach($cols as $cols2) {
    $stmt.=" :".implode(",", $cols2)." ";
}
$stmt.=" ) ";

$stmt2 = $pdo_conn->prepare($stmt);
foreach($cols as $cols2) {
    $stmt2->bindParam(':$cols2', $cols2);
}
```

but i now get the error about the implode:

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/integra/public_html/admin/includes/functions.php on line 18
>
> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/integra/public_html/admin/includes/functions.php on line 22

which i think is because there is nothing to implode as there is only one column and one value

Comment: Read the error message.  The error has nothing to do with PDO.  It's just telling you that the argument to `foreach()` is wrong.  What are `$values` and `$cols`?  They don't seem to be arrays, according to the error message.

Comment: Actually, I think `:$cols2` is intended there, _but_ with a _double-quoted_ string instead of single-quoted so that `$cols2` is interpolated and prepended with `:`.

Comment: Why are you even doing a foreach loop to set $values2 equal to itself??

Comment: Be careful with your quoting. Anywhere you expect a variable to be expanded in a quoted string, it needs to be double-quoted, not single-quoted., example `$stmt2->bindParam(":$cols2", $cols2);`

Comment: well the function will be used for many insert queries so some queries may have 2 columns to insert to and others may have more

Answer (score 2):

Use type hints to ensure the function arguments are arrays:

```
function InsertQuery ($table, array $cols, array $values) {
```

Make sure your PDO connection is accessible. If it's global, you have to declare it (credit to @u_mulder):

```
    global $pdo_conn;
```

The following does nothing, get rid of it:

```
    foreach($values as $values2) {
        $values2 = $values2;
    }
```

Use builtin array functions instead of foreach'ing everything:

```
    $col_list = implode(",", $cols);
    $param_list = implode(",", array_fill(1,count($cols), "?"));
```

Variables don't expand inside single-quotes. You need to use double-quotes (credit to @MichaelBerkowski).

Also, use $stmt for a PDOStatement object, and not for the SQL string. That's confusing.

```
    $sql="INSERT into $table ($col_list) VALUES ($param_list)";

    $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
```

You don't need to write a foreach loop to bindParam() in PDO. You can just pass an array of values to execute(). And you already have the values in an array, so it's really easy:

```
    $stmt->execute($values);

}
```

---

For extra safety, make sure to delimit the columns, in case someone uses special characters or a SQL keyword in a column name:

```
    $col_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($c) { return "`$c`" }, $cols));
```

And make sure the values is in a simple array, not an associative array:

```
    $stmt->execute(array_values($values));
```

---

Re your comment:

> would you be able to show me how to do the same with select, I'm not sure how it would work as if i have a where clause what would i do with it in the function?

One could for example design a function with an argument `$where` that is an *associative array*, whose keys are column names, and whose values are the values you're searching for.

Assume the resulting WHERE clause includes these column/value pairs as `AND` terms, and all the comparisons are equality.

```
function SelectQuery($table, array $where) {
    global $pdo_conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ";
    $values = null;
    if ($where) {
        $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", 
            array_map(function ($c) { return "`$c` = ?"; } array_keys($where)));
        $values = array_values($where);
    }
    $stmt = $pdo_con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($values);
}
```

Of course this supports only a small subset of the possible expressions you can have in a SELECT, but I'm just demonstrating a technique here.

If you want a more fully-feature query builder for PHP, take a look at [Zend_Db_Sql](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html) or [Doctrine QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) or [Laravel query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries).

---

> if anything changes on my server and the PDO stops working i can revert back to MySQL while i fix it.

PDO has been stable since 2005 and it will not stop working, unless you change your PHP environment and disable the extension or the mysql driver or something.

Whereas the ext/mysql extension *will* stop working. It is currently deprecated and PHP has announced they will remove it in a future version of PHP.

Comment: that seems to work perfect! where does the $values come from?

Comment: also the $col_list, where is the $c coming from?

Comment: `$values` is one of the arguments to your InsertQuery() function.

Comment: aha perfect - thank you. Would it be possible to do something similar for a SELECT query in PDO?

Comment: [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map) automatically loops over the elements of `$cols` and passes each one as an argument to the function callback, which I defined as an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). I called that argument `$c`.

Comment: Sure, you could use the same techniques for a SELECT query, but typically an INSERT is going to follow a more predictable syntax. For this reason, it's easier to create a generic insert-into-anything function than it would be to create a generic select-from-anything function.

Comment: would you be able to show me how to do the same with select, I'm not sure how it would work as if i have a where clause what would i do with it in the function?

Comment: i want to be able to have the ability of the functions to use MySQL and PDO, so if i do select * from $table where sequence = :seq how could i make that also work in SQL. Reason for this is if anything changes on my server and the PDO stops working i can revert back to MySQL while i fix it. i am very new to PDO so i want the ability to revert back anytime temporarily while i look at any issues

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, i have just tried your update but i am getting a syntax error on the $sql.= line

Comment: I typed it in yesterday without testing it. I checked the syntax with `php -l` just now, but I get no syntax errors. I'm using PHP 5.3.26.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on:

First, `$cols` and `$vals` should be arrays, but they are strings.

Quick fix is to make them arrays:

```
$col = array('col1');
$val = array('val1');
InsertQuery("table1", $col, $val);
```

Second, `$pdo_conn` is unknown in the function scope. Make it a parameter or a global.

Comment: `$pdo_conn` should also be defined as global or passed as an argument.

Comment: check my edit, the error has changed and i make the vars arrays

Comment: @charliejsford you resulting SQL statement is wrong. Do `echo $stmt;` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this for create query from array:

```
$myArray = array(
             'col1' => 'val1',
             'col2' => 'val2'
           );

$query = "INSERT INTO table (" . implode(", ", array_keys($myArray)) . ") VALUES (" . implode(", ", $myArray) . ")";
```

maybe usefull for you
http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: At first I thought this was good approach but then realized this doesn't sanitize the input. Since this is specifically talking about PDO, I would think modifying to escape the values would be good.

Comment: @BrianFLeighty this is simple way how to create sql insert query. About escaping..you can escape values before eg. in array. 'col1' => htmlspecialchars('val1') or make a simple function which validate your data entry. This is idea for you. You can combine or make another way how to resolve your problem.